# PHP syntax error or access violation: 1064 - using variable in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

Pulling my hair out on this one, I've tried a number of things in terms of changing the escape characters for the variable and nothing is working including changing to '". $r."' etc.

If I hard code the variable to a constant it works. e.g $r = "Word";

I've renamed the variables to random letters in case they were reserved words.

I've gone as far as setting up logging for mysql and I have compared the statements and they're identical, the only difference being one is submitted via text box and the other has been set by constant.

Model:

```
 public static function searchProfile()
    {
    $r = Request::post('w');
    $args = "";
    if ($r) {$args = "`info_tradingstatus` = '$r'";}
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT profile_id, profile_name FROM profile_seeker WHERE $args";
```

View:

```
  <input type="text" name="w" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keyword" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Controller:

```
public function search_action()
{
ProfileModel::searchProfile(
Request::post('w'),
Redirect::to('profile/searchresults'));
}
```

Comment: `info_tradingstatus` have different quotation than `$r`, did you test for this?

Comment: Look up *Prepared Statements* and use something like  `where somecol = ? or ? is null`

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Yes I have tried with and without quotations, both work. As said, it works if I set $r = "answer"; but if I enter "answer" to a input field it does not work despite both the queries being the same in mysql.

Comment: Is your charset defined to UTF-8 for both php and html?

Comment: Checked, it wasn't previously however I have now set it and still same issues, @AedixRhinedale

Comment: Can you show us the static method `post` from `Request` class?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem is when the $r is empty, please try:

```
public static function searchProfile()
    {
    $r = Request::post('w');
    $args = " 1 ";
    if ($r) {$args = "`info_tradingstatus` = '".$r."'";} // just in case
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT profile_id, profile_name FROM profile_seeker WHERE $args";
```

Comment: Tried the above and this didn't work. The mysql log showed this as what was executed: FROM profile_seeker WHERE  1

Comment: it means that error is lower at the code. give lower code